# GraphQL not loading children lists

Tags: node.js, graphql

I had started out writing verbose GraphQL and switched to `graphql-tools` and `makeExecutableSchema` and with the changes it will load queries for `user(id: "N")`, `users`, `group(id: "N")` and `groups`, however, the nested lists just return `"id": null`. I feel like I have to have a small mistake somewhere but am not seeing it:

```
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')

const db = require('./db')

const typeDefs = `
  type User {
    id: String
    first_name: String!
    last_name: String!
    email: String!
    friends: [User!]
    groups: [Group!]
  }

  type Group {
    id: String
    name: String!
  }

  type Query {
    users: [User!]!
    user(id: String!): User
    groups: [Group!]!
    group(id: String!): Group
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: db.readAllUsers,
    user: (root, args, { loaders }) => loaders.user.load(args.id),
    groups: db.readAllGroups,
    group: (root, args, { loaders }) => loaders.group.load(args.id)
  }
}

module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit: to clarify, [here's what the data source looks like](https://github.com/Fluidbyte/graphql-example/blob/master/server/db.js#L12-L19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined resolvers for your queries, while are just fields on your Query type. However, you don't have any resolvers for the `group` field on the `User` type, so GraphQL falls back to using the default resolver for that field. Since the property field on the Object `User` resolves to is just an array of ids, GraphQL doesn't know how to make sense of it -- after all, you told it groups would be an array of objects.

You'll need to add a resolver for the `groups` field and transform that array into a Promise that will resolve to an array of `Group` objects:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: db.readAllUsers,
    user: (root, args, { loaders }) => loaders.user.load(args.id),
    groups: db.readAllGroups,
    group: (root, args, { loaders }) => loaders.group.load(args.id)
  },
  User: {
    groups: ({ groups }, args, { loaders }) => {
      return Promise.all(groups.map(id => loaders.group.load(id)))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified there is a [groups property](https://github.com/Fluidbyte/graphql-example/blob/master/server/db.js#L12-L19) on the object being returned

Comment: So, in your example above, I can get the id of the user, would I need to manually then get the `user.groups` and iterate over those to populate that?

Comment: Yup. I modified the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you! It just "clicked" seeing your code, I wasn't thinking about the full object coming through the args on `User.groups`.

Comment: One last sticking point: is there a way to use the loaders in the `User.groups` resolver? I'm not seeing the context being passed through...

Comment: I didn't include it in the example, but context by definition should be available to every resolver.